# regarding primary and foreign keys

Tags: sql-server

If I have a table1 with primary key as TitleID and I want to make this one as Foreign key in Table2, do the names of both keys have to be same? Like in Table2, do I need to create a column named TitleID only?? Can I name this Foreign key as PageTitleID?

Comment: I propose to change the titel: Can two columns used as primary key and as foreign key have the same name. **Regarding** doesn't describe the Question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The names of the keys are not important.

You can name the foreign key PageTitleID if you wish.  I commonly name the primary key field "ID" in all of my tables, and then reference them by a descriptive name as a foreign key ("AuthorID" when joining with the "ID" field of the Authors table).  Other developers name their keys the same, but it isn't necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Name them what you want then do this

```
ALTER TABLE Table2
ADD FOREIGN KEY (PageTitleID) REFERENCES Table1(TitleID);
```

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: @marc_s I appreciate the edit. Considering I wrote this around midnight new years eve I'm surprised I was even speaking coherent English.